# How to fix .htaccess RewriteRule conflict?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have conflict RewriteRule .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe.php$/template/site.org/newsletter/unsubscribe.php
RewriteRule ^(unsubscribe)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

**This**

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**Conflict with**

```
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe.php$/template/site.org/newsletter/unsubscribe.php
RewriteRule ^(unsubscribe)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `unsubscribe` rule needs a space between pattern and target but more importantly you need to place these rules before catch-all `index.php` rule. You can also combine 2 last rules into one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^unsubscribe(?:\.php)?$ /template/site.org/newsletter/unsubscribe.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @anubhava. It's working perfectly.